# Can you allow one of a few types of pointers as an argument without void*?

Tags: c, function, pointers, overloading, generic-programming

In plain [c](/questions/tagged/c), I have a situation where I would like to allow a function to accept multiple types of pointers.  To illustrate my situation, here could be one use case:

```
void myfunction([int* or char*] value) {
    *value = 0xdd;  // safe since value is at least as big as a char*
}
```

And here is another:

```
#define MAGIC 0xabcdef0
typedef struct {
    int magic;
    char* content;
} MyStruct;

void myfunction([int* or MyStruct*] value) {
    if (*value != MAGIC) {
        printf("Got an int\n");
    } else {
        printf("Got a MyStruct\n");
    }
}

// example:
int input1 = 0;
MyStruct input2 = { MAGIC, "hello world" };
myfunction(input1);  // "Got an int"
myfunction(input2);  // "Got a MyStruct"
```

Both of these situations could be made possible with a `void*` parameter type, but that would in effect allow any type of pointer to be passed in without a compile error.  Is there a way to restrict the function to accept only a specific subset of pointer types?

Comment: When calling `myfunction()` what is the reason for not passing an additional parameter indicating the type?  Easy enough to do with `_Generic` with scant extra coding cost.

Comment: `0xdd;` will not fit in `char` (it will in `unsigned char`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, nitpick: `char` may be an unsigned type.

Comment: Yes, I'm used to being corrected for not nitpicking -- damned if you do, damned if you don't `:)`

Comment: Yes, you can, but it is poor programming style, as you are on your own on type checking and the compiler will not assist you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use features that are new in C11, the `_Generic` keyword can solve your problem:

```
void myfunction(void *value) {
    // ...
}
#define myfunction(x) myfunction( \
    _Generic((x), char *: (x), int *: (x)) )
```

Comment: How would you handle the assignment of `*value = 0xdd;` in the `_Generic` case above? Wouldn't you need to define two functions, e.g. `myfunc_char` and `myfunc_int` to provide for in the expansion of the macro? (or am I just reading the answer too literally?)

Comment: Thanks!  Something along these lines is what I was looking for.  This can enable the function to be called with either type of argument without requiring that the argument be wrapped in a union.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: There are lots of other problems with what OP wants to do, but I felt like they're beyond the scope of the question as stated. However they can also be solved with `_Generic` (using different underlying functions for each pointer type).

Comment: OK, that's where I was scratching my head. I was just trying to read to literally concerned there were holes in my `_Generic` understanding. It's clear now what was intended. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: It makes more sense with OP's second example where either way there's an `int` that's valid to access via `int *`, but where the pointer passed may be to a `struct` containing an `int` as its first member. In this case you might not need separate functions, just the `_Generic` construct I described.

Answer (score 1):

As Houman pointed out, you can use a union to do the job, however, you still have the problem that you must identify the type that is set in the union type. You can solve that using an enum to identify the type inside your function.

```c
union myUnion {
    int* intPointer,
    MyStruct* myStructPointer
};

enum typeEnum {
    INT,
    MYSTRUCT
};

void myfunction(union myUnion union, enum typeEnum type) {
    if (type == INT)
         // you got an integer
    else if (type == MYSTRUCT)
         // you got a struct
    // You can add future additions here
 }
```

Comment: `typeEnum.INT` and `typeEnum.MYSTRUCT` should just be `INT` and `MYSTRUCT`. Also `myUnion` and `typeEnum` should be `union myUnion` and `enum typeEnum`.

Comment: I can't use a union is because this involves changing an argument to a public method in a library, one that currently has an int* parameter.  I can't change the method signature (other than changing pointer types) because that would break backwards binary compatibility.  Normally though a union would be the right choice.

Answer (score 0):

No, use `void*` and then cast.

One could think that I can use a `void*` and then check about the casting inside the function, and if not the expected type, raise an error, but no, you cannot do that either, since [`void*` loses all its type information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099384/how-to-check-if-a-void-pointer-can-be-safely-cast-to-something-else).

<sub>Damn I am writing just before going into the shower. I couldn't resist! BRB :) -- OK, turns out R..'s answer from the *future* is the correct one! ;)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
void myfunction(void *s)
{
    if ( *(int *)s == MAGIC )
    {
        MyStruct *p = s;
        printf("%s\n", p->content);
    }
}
```

However this design makes it easy to write buggy code that the compiler will not catch for you, so I would recommend coming up with a slightly different design (e.g. tagged unions).