# Dynamically determine the type of a function parameter in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, casting, void-pointers

In JavaScript I can have a function with an untyped argument, and then customize the behavior depending on the type:

```
function customize(a) {
  if (a instanceof Uint8Array) {
    doArray()
  } else if (typeof a == 'function') {
    doFunction()
  } else {
    doOther()
  }
}
```

How can I do this same thing in C, either with or without macros (preferrably without macros).

```
void
customize(void *a) {
  // ???
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099384/how-to-check-if-a-void-pointer-can-be-safely-cast-to-something-else) it says:

> Your void pointer looses all its type information, so by that alone, you cannot check if it can be cast safely. It's up to the programmer to know if a void* can be cast safely to a type.

Can I somehow do a comparison against the key functions or structs in my application to see if it is a match?

```
void
customize(void *a) {
  if (a == fn_a) return do_function();
  if (a == fn_b) return do_function();
  // somehow iterate dynamically through the functions.
}

void
fn_a() {

}
```

Comment: How about a second parameter, which tells the function what it should do with `a`?

Comment: I want the API to be exactly like this.

Comment: No, you can't do it directly. There is absolutely no way to find out what `a` points to. However if is is guaranteed that `a` points to some `struct` where the first field contains some type information, then it could be done.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from checking what the pointer points to, but note that casting a function pointer to `void*` is UB. I.e. there is no guarantee that a function pointer will fit into a data pointer and vice versa. You can cast to a different *function* pointer before returning to the original one. So you would at least need a union and a flag to tell you which of the two pointers to use. But then you get to what @mch proposed above (with an added caveat that you need the union).

Comment: I always wanted to give an answer like this (which I always hated): you are doing it wrong. C is a statically typed language. Loosing and recovering type information is not part of the design of the language.

Comment: BTW your `a == fn_a` comparisions are bogous, because `a` will never point to a _function_ but only to some data.
Don't try to mimic JavaScrip concepts with C, the two languages are _totally_ different.

Comment: There's no dynamic type system, you'll have to implement it manually with enums. You can however get static type checks at compile-time with `_Generic`, which is good enough for sane program designs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was stated in the thread you've found, it is not possible through `void *`.

You can do something similar with unions, but it's not very flexible and I'm not sure it is a good solution (might be better to have separate functions for every type):

```
typedef enum {
    TYPE_1 = 0,
    TYPE_2,
    TYPE_3
} type_e;

typedef union {
    int     t1;
    char    t2[5];
    double  t3;
} types_u;

typedef struct {
    type_e type;
    types_u types;
} my_types_t;


void func(my_types_t *some_variable)
{
    switch (some_variable->type)
    {
        case TYPE_1:
            // do something 
            break;
        case TYPE_2:
            // do something else
            break;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an old saying that *you can write FORTRAN in any language*.  I'm not sure if it is true or not, but I'm sure that you can't write Javascript in any language and especially not in C.

C is statically typed and all type information is lost at runtime.  You'll have to rethink your design, perhaps avoiding completely the need of carrying the information, perhaps passing an additional parameter with that information, perhaps bundling it with the `void*` in a struct, perhaps assuming that the `void*` point to something you have more information about and you can reextract the type information.  There are several techniques possible, all with various trade-off and caveats, but expanding on them seems like writing a book and I don't have time for that.

Some of the techniques were made language features in C++; that would avoid you to have to reinvent them and reimplement them, but you'd need to learn another language.